# Consulta retornar array's específicos de documentos mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Tenho a seguinte documento chamado "CURSO":

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58a300ff3de08a3cdce471be"),    
    "nome" : "Matemática",
    "turma" : [ 
        {
            "professor" : {
                "nome" : "Maria",
                "usuarioId" : ObjectId("58a2f129c685a21b88ccee84")
            },
            "aluno" : [ 
                {
                    "nome" : "Pedro",
                    "usuarioId" : ObjectId("58a2f208c685a21b88ccee86")
                }, 
                {
                    "nome" : "Marcio",
                    "usuarioId" : ObjectId("58a723964530540a70e2b37b")
                }
            ],
            "_id" : ObjectId("58a3035e503e932c909553ea"),
            "turno" : "Matutino",
            "nome" : "Matemática 1"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("58a3036c503e932c909553eb"),
            "professor" : {
                "nome" : "João",
                "usuarioId" : ObjectId("58a2f129c685a21b88ccee84")
            },
            "aluno" : [ 
                {
                    "nome" : "José",
                    "usuarioId" : ObjectId("58a2f208c685a21b88ccee86")
                }
            ],            
            "turno" : "Noturno",
            "nome" : "Matemática 2"
        }
    ]    
}
```

Estou tentando fazer uma consulta que retorne apenas as turmas que um determinado aluno esta inserido, mas minha consulta esta retornando todas turmas, mesmo o aluno fazendo parte de apenas uma das turmas deste curso, um exemplo de como esta sendo feita a consulta:

```
db.getCollection('cursos').find(    
    { turma: { $elemMatch: { 'aluno.usuarioId': ObjectId("58a723964530540a70e2b37b") } } }
)
```

O resultado desta consulta ele acaba trazendo as turmas "Matemática 1" e "Matemática 2", gostaria de saber se tem como fazer uma consulta que retorne apenas as turmas que o aluno faz parte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar `$elemMatch` na projeção também:

```
db.getCollection('cursos').find(
  {turma: {$elemMatch: {'aluno.usuarioId': ObjectId("58a723964530540a70e2b37b")}}},
  {turma: {$elemMatch: {'aluno.usuarioId': ObjectId("58a723964530540a70e2b37b")}}, nome: 1},
)
```

Veja [mais sobre projeção com `$elemMatch` aqui](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/#proj._S_elemMatch).

Comment: Perfeito Ezequias, muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente!!.